# How can I resolve maskedInput error: Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'?

Tags: visual-studio, mask, maskedtextbox, maskedinput

*Tools*

- jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js (DigitalBush)
- Visual Studio 2012 SP1
- .NET Framework 4.5
- MVC Runtime v4.0.30319
- Windows 7
- IE 9 64-bit
- jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
- The full panoply of References MS supplies with a new Web MVC project

*Issue*

I had been successfully using the maskedInput until very recently. Now I get the error:

**0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'mask'**

I have two  elements, one for 10 digits and one for 4, displaying and hiding them as needed. The error occurs during page initialization on the first line of the function under Pager initialization. Microsoft JS complains that 'mask' is undefined. Here is my code.

[image]

I don't know what has happened to cause the non-recognition of the mask. I have tried reordering the placement of the maskedInput among other scripts. I wonder if this plugin is now incompatible with the progressive, frenetic changes in nearly every aspect of web development. Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on and its resolution?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Never Mind! I had a Homer moment! I ported the app to VS 2012 , but neglected to update that reference link! Apologies!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind! I had a Homer moment! I ported the app to VS 2012 , but neglected to update that reference link! Apologies!